# Creating submenu dropdown accordion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, accordion

I'm pretty hard struggling with **CSS/JS** for a long time so here is my problem: I want to **modify my current accordion** menu (demo source: **https://codepen.io/fainder/pen/qBwBeO**)

`please check the code samples in codepen snippets`

by adding submenus to it like here: **https://codepen.io/LewisBriffa/pen/qjwqLb**

I will continue to try to create the submenu myself, however, I would welcome any advice or examples you might give me. Many thanks for yours any attention

Comment: You want *your* accordion created in 2014 to be combined with an accordion created in 2017 so *you* have a new accordion? Just making sure....

Comment: To be honest, I just want to modify the first accordion to have the submenus in it like in the second accordion example (sub panel in the panel). Not my code snippets for sure, but I used the first one in my study project. @RenevanderLende